# Is the dehomogenisation of smooth homogeneous polynomial smooth?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-space

If $F\in\mathbb{C}[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n+1}]$ is a smooth homogeneous polynomial, is it true that the dehomogenisation $F(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n},1)\in\mathbb{C}[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]$ is also smooth?

Smooth in this context meaning non-singular.

I know that the converse is false; i.e. if we consider a smooth polynomial $f$ then its homogenisation is not always smooth.

Comment: Isn't every polynomial smooth?

Comment: I mean smooth as in non-singular, sorry I will edit this in

Comment: The only smooth homogeneous polynomials are linear ones, others have a singularity at the origin.

Comment: @Mohan While true, in general dehomogenisation might removed that singularity.

Comment: @red_trumpet He seems to be assuming (if I understand correctly) that $F$ is smooth.

Comment: I am assuming that the singularity at the origin is negligible. Explicitly if $F$ is smooth (away from the origin), then is the dehomogenisation also smooth?